# Errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT', when connecting gcloud mysql with sails js

Tags: sails.js, gcloud

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have deployed node sailsjs app in gCloud and created mysql instance in gCloud but I am getting mysql connection error. I have configured below configuration in datastores object into production file like:

```
default: {
      adapter: 'sails-mysql',
      host: 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
      user:'root',
      password:'xxxx',
      database:'xxxx',
      port: 3306
}
```

But I am getting this error each time:

> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOTeY.png

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message seems that the sails js app is not reaching the Cloud SQL server.

This could happen because the Public IP of your client machine is not allowed on the authorized networks of your Cloud SQL instance.

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/authorize-networks

1. Go to the Cloud SQL Instances page in the Google Cloud Console.
2. Click the instance name to open its Instance details page.
3. Select the Connections tab.
4. Click Add network.
5. In the Network field, enter the IP address or address range you want to allow connections from. ...
6. Optionally, enter a name for this entry.
7. Click Done.

"If you find yourself encountering a "Handshake inactivity timeout" error when your Sails app interacts with MySQL, you can increase the timeout using the connectTimeout option. This is usually only necessary when queries are running side-by-side with computationally expensive operations (for example, compiling client-side typescript files or running webpack during development)."

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/adapters/available-adapters

Comment: Hi @Mario, Thanks for your reply. I have follow the above instructions and added my IP address. I am able to connect with gcloud mysql from local DB by added necessary credentials But getting same error as before when try to configure with sails js. I attached screenshot for the same for reference. Please check once and help me to resolve this issue.